# Qt5 QWebView how to send client certificate?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, ssl, https, certificate

I use Qt5's QWebView to load a https website, which need client certificate. I have installed client certificate and used chrome and ie browser to test ok. But it didn't work in the QWebView.

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("https://mysite.com/default2.aspx"));

QSslConfiguration conf = request.sslConfiguration();
//get the client certificate
QByteArray certData = getCertInWindowsMyStore(); 
QSslCertificate sslCert(certData, QSsl::Der);
conf.setLocalCertificate(sslCert);

request.setSslConfiguration(conf);

ui->webView->load(request);
```

I print the certicate's subjectinfo which is correct.
I seach some infomation from google. Someone says I have to set the private key, someone didn't set and it also works fine. How it works? And I think that I used chrome browser to visit that website, it works fine, but chrome wouldn't know the private key, so I think there's no need to set private key.
Does anyone know how to do? This question has tortured me very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think to load private key you have to add to your code:

```
 QByteArray keyData = customReadFile("/path/to/privatekey/PEM");
 QSslKey sslPrivateKey(keyData, QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Pem, QSsl::PrivateKey, "PRIVATE KEY PASS");
 conf.setPrivateKey(sslPrivateKey);
```

You have to implement customReadFile()